# Oracle SQL - SUM total of similar rows while only displaying first occurrence of each

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sum

The title is a little tricky but here is what I would like to accomplish. I am using Oracle SQL Developer, 11G express. I have a table where users will enter data over a period of time. I would like to be able to pull that data by country_code and date range. Here is my table (RETURN_STATISTICS):

```
RETURN_ID   COUNTRY_CODE  CODE    DESCRIPTION   RETURN TOTAL   DATE
1           1             0001    Example 1      1             12-Aug-2012
2           1             0002    Example 2      1             13-Aug-2012
3           1             0003    Example 3      1             14-Aug-2012
4           1             0004    Example 4      1             13-Aug-2012
5           1             0005    Example 5      1             11-Aug-2012
6           1             0006    Example 6      1             13-Aug-2012
7           2             0001    Example 1      1             12-Aug-2012
8           2             0002    Example 2      1             13-Aug-2012
9           2             0003    Example 3      1             14-Aug-2012
10          2             0004    Example 4      1             13-Aug-2012
11          2             0005    Example 5      1             11-Aug-2012
12          2             0006    Example 6      1             13-Aug-2012
...        ...            ....    ......         ..            ......
300         1             0004    Example 4      1             10-Aug-2013
500         1             0001    Example 1      6             12-Aug-2014
....        ...           .....   .......        ...           .....
```

I want to query by country_code and date range and return 1 occurrence for each CODE with the overall RETURN_TOTAL for that CODE displayed. Here is what I want my output to look like for country_code = 1, Date range Aug 9, 2012 - Aug 15, 2014.

```
CODE      DESCRIPTION                                        RETURN_TOTAL
--------- -------------------------------------------------- ------------
0001      Example 1                                               7
0002      Example 2                                               1 
0003      Example 3                                               1 
0004      Example 4                                               2 
0005      Example 5                                               1      
0006      Example 6                                               1
```

Notice Example 1 is 7 (6+1) and  Example 4 is 2 (1+1). Here is the SQL that I tried and its result. I know what is wrong with my SQL I just don't know how to fix it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CODE,
    DESCRIPTION,
 (SELECT SUM(RETURN_TOTAL) FROM RETURN_STATISTICS 
          WHERE COUNTRY_CODE = 1 AND DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE ('08/09/2012 10:10:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MI:SS') AND TO_DATE ('08/15/2014 12:10:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MI:SS') AND CODE = 0001) as RETURN_TOTAL
FROM RETURN_STATISTICS
  WHERE COUNTRY_CODE = 1
ORDER BY CODE
```

Result:

```
CODE      DESCRIPTION                                        RETURN_TOTAL
--------- -------------------------------------------------- ------------
0001      Example 1                                               7
0002      Example 2                                               7 
0003      Example 3                                               7 
0004      Example 4                                               7 
0005      Example 5                                               7      
0006      Example 6                                               7
```

Is there a way to get total for each CODE? I know I'm setting it to 0001 but is there a way to make it use each code as a reference for the RETURN_TOTAL? Perhaps a table join, which I still don't know how to do correctly? Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) go a long way here.  You can use `row_number() over (... order by newid())` to pick a random description:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by code
                    order by newid()) as rn
        ,       sum(return_total) over (partition by code) as return_total
        ,       code
        ,       description
        from    return_statistics
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1 -- Only one row per code
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much for your efforts!